# Editing SVG Image

Tags: svg

I (think I) have some SVG code. I'm trying to edit one of the icons in the [iron-icon](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-icons/blob/master/iron-icons.html) set. That set includes the SVG code nested in a `iron-iconset-svg` element. I'm new to working with SVG icons. How can I edit these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally would open them up in something like Illustrator, but from what I can see in the github, it looks like the icons aren't saved anywhere as individual files?

If that is the case, then you would need to get the code like this:

`<g id="accessibility"><path d="M12 2c1.1 0 2 .9 2 2s-.9 2-2 2-2-.9-2-2 .9-2 2-2zm9 7h-6v13h-2v-6h-2v6H9V9H3V7h18v2z"/></g>`

and save it in a text editor as an `.svg` file. You may need to add more info to make it work, in which case look at this link: view-source:http://s.cdpn.io/3/kiwi.svg and replace the `<ellipse>` and `<path>` with the code above.

Comment: Its so odd. I took the above and pasted it into the SVG-edit tool https://svg-edit.github.io/svgedit/releases/svg-edit-2.8.1/svg-editor.html and it says there's a parse error.

Comment: You need to paste it in after the `<title>` like this:
 <g><title>Layer 1</title><!-- PASTE YOUR LINE HERE --></g>